# Why does BigQuery do a full table scan for `SELECT *` with a WHERE clause referencing just one column?

Tags: google-bigquery

Why does BigQuery perform a full table scan for `SELECT *` when a WHERE clause is provided?

```
SELECT *
FROM `githubarchive.month.202012` 
WHERE login='__ThisUserDoesNotExist__'
```

This query performs a full table scan, even though it really just needs to do a full scan of the login column to determine that there are no records to return. Interested in references to relevant sections of BQ docs as well as papers on query planning for columnar databases.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery Is a [columnar storage](https://cloud.google.com/files/BigQueryTechnicalWP.pdf), with out partition/clustering on table it will do a full table scan.

Comment: I've updated the example to better illustrate my point. Even with columnar storage, it could still just scan the login column to figure out no records would be returned. I agree it has to do a full scan of the login column no matter what to figure out which records are relevant. But once it's done that, why is it then doing a full table scan of the entire table?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is doing a full table scan because the query asks for all the column to be output.

You'll find only the `login` column is scanned with query below:

```
SELECT login
FROM `githubarchive.month.202012` 
WHERE login='__ThisUserDoesNotExist__'
```

Check public documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing

> BigQuery uses a columnar data structure. You're charged according to the total data processed in the columns you select, and the total data per column is calculated based on the types of data in the column. For more information about how your data size is calculated, see Data size calculation.

Comment: Thanks Yun! This behavior implies that the data is read in full before filtering is applied. 
 The reasons for this are still a bit opaque to me even after reading the Dremel paper and analyzing the query execution plan. Could you point me towards any documentation for the BigQuery that goes into detail about the the query planner and specifies that data read in full before filtering occurs?

Comment: The alternative to reading then filtering would be to first compute the filter mask and then retrieve only those values matching the filter.  So you could directly access the blocks within each columnar store that hold the values you are interested in.

Comment: Added the reference to the answer